# Why can't I edit peoples posts?

Tags: support, reputation

I used to be able to edit peoples posts. I want to do it again (to change the $\mathcal P$ to $\wp$ in [the thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8321/a-torus-and-the-weierstrass-p-function)) can someone fix this please?

Comment: Since the site graduated I think the reputation levels required to do some actions have increased, no?

Comment: More precisely, the power alluded to in the question went from a 1000 rep threashold to a 2000 rep one. Notice that you also can no longer vote to close or re-open questions, which now takes 3000 (instead of 500).

Comment: @Willie: That's strange -- the increase function isn't monotonic?!

Comment: @Rahul: No, it isn't. The SE people have a justification for this. I don't quite remember it, but it has something to do with how in the Beta stage they want it to be more democratic so the tone/level of the website best approach what potential users want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Graduated sites have higher reputation requirement to access privileges. In particular,  [you need 2,000 rep for editing](https://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit), where now you only have 1,820.

The privileges page https://math.stackexchange.com/privileges for how far you are away from reaching the needed rep.

See [*Promotion implies higher rep needed for privileges, and nobody has such*](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/984/promotion-implies-higher-rep-needed-for-privileges-and-nobody-has-such) on this site for a discussion on this issue.